# How to find the column product column in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, triangle

I've Dataframe like this:

```
  DP 1    DP 2    DP 3    DP 4    DP 5    DP 6    DP 7    DP 8    DP 9   DP 10
 2.720   1.748   1.462   1.228   1.152   1.055   1.063   1.080   1.001  
 4.361   1.641   1.430   1.117   1.181   1.018   1.052   1.096      
 3.345   1.840   1.505   1.262   1.115   1.095   1.053          
 2.663   1.748   1.352   1.256   1.051   1.119              
 3.494   1.907   1.506   1.108   1.091                  
 3.104   1.559   1.458   1.092                      
 2.978   1.484   1.374                          
 3.066   1.695                              
 2.876                                                          
 1.179   1.699   1.439   1.179   1.116   1.073   1.055   1.089   1.001   1.000
```

I've to find this :

```
 4.680   3.971   2.337   1.624   1.377   1.234   1.150   1.090   1.001   1.000
```

By the formula:
i've to find the product of last row first element and rest of element,i.e: product(1.179 to 1.000)=4.680
then next  product(1.699 to 1.000)=3.971 and so on...

`PRODUCT(first:last)`

`PRODUCT(second:last)`

`PRODUCT(third:last)`

so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe already has that last row, such that `df.iloc[[-1]]` is:

```py
 DP 1   DP 2   DP 3   DP 4   DP 5   DP 6   DP 7   DP 8   DP 9  DP 10
1.179  1.699  1.439  1.179  1.116  1.073  1.055  1.089  1.001    1.0
```

Reverse the series and take the [cumulative product](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html):

```py
df.iloc[-1][::-1].cumprod()
# output
DP 10    1.000000
DP 9     1.001000
DP 8     1.090089
DP 7     1.150044
DP 6     1.233997
DP 5     1.377141
DP 4     1.623649
DP 3     2.336431
DP 2     3.969596
DP 1     4.680154
```

And to get it back in the original order, reverse the result:

```py
df.iloc[-1][::-1].cumprod()[::-1]
# output
DP 1     4.680154
DP 2     3.969596
DP 3     2.336431
DP 4     1.623649
DP 5     1.377141
DP 6     1.233997
DP 7     1.150044
DP 8     1.090089
DP 9     1.001000
DP 10    1.000000
```

(These numbers appear slightly different because you've rounded them in your question.)

Comment: Thank you..! I want in a row .

Comment: I don't think you should add it in a row but - the result above is a Series, so to add it as a row, do: `result = df.iloc[-1][::-1].cumprod()[::-1]` and then `df = df.append(result, ignore_index=True)`